# "After age 70" or "after the age of 70"?

Tags: prepositions, articles, numbers

I cannot really find an answer:

I know commonly we say "at the age of 70". But when I see sentences with "after", there is typically no article or preposition, and it becomes simply "after age 70". Is that truly correct?

Comment: I think your observation is wrong, and both forms are common: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=after+the+age+of+50%2Cafter+age+50&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cafter%20the%20age%20of%2050%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cafter%20age%2050%3B%2Cc0

Comment: What did you do to find an answer? A simple Google search should answer it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all possible and idiomatic

> at the age of 70

> at age 70

> after the age of 70

> after age 70

Don't try to analyse the interior structure of "age 70" as nouns, adjectives etc.  It is one of the various idiomatic expressions of time with numbers:  "5 o'clock" "March third" or "age 70"